# Prove that rational numbers $a,b$ are integers if $a+b$ and $ab$ are integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I have been trying to prove this via divisibility, assuming that $a=\frac{n}{m}$ and $b=\frac{r}{q}$ for some $n,m,r,q$ in

Ints($m$,$q$ not $0$), but I'm completely stuck here. Any help?

Comment: If $x$ is divisibly by $p$ and $y$ is divisible by $q$ then $xy$ is divisible by $pq$. And so is $qx$, $py$, and $qx+py$.

Comment: Note that conversely, $a+b,ab$ both integers means either that $a,b$ are both integers or both non-rational.  E.g., $a=1+\sqrt 2,b=1-\sqrt 2$.

Comment: is there a way to prove this by disproving the contradiction? Specifically, we can case this by when a,b are both non-integers, and when one of a or b is an integer.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Apply the [rational root theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rational-root-theorem/) to

$$ x^2 - ( a + b) x + ab $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $n:=a+b$ and $m:=ab.$ Then $a^2-an+m=0$ and hence $$a=\dfrac{n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}}{2}.$$ note that since $a\in\Bbb Q,$ then $n^2-4m$ must be a perfect square.

Then necessarily $2\mid n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}$ (if $n$ is odd, then $n^2-4m$ is odd $\Longrightarrow$ $n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}$ is even; if $n$ is even, then $n^2-4m$ is even $\Longrightarrow$ $n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}$ is even).